# Php showing updated mysql is not being updated?

Tags: php, sql-update, set, html

Sorry this is a pretty hefty page so if you can look over this and tell me why its not updating my database but the php page here is the first page where i grab college_id and my value i want to update and as soon as vote is clicked it does a simple math equation to update total, that then gets divided to get percentage.

```
Sorry if you cant understand me been stressed over this project.
```

Code woulnd not go inside of codebox so heres link.
[enter link description here](http://pastebin.com/cPqTVYc0)

Btw it's on line 30 wheres its not updating to db but only on php page
EDIT: FOUND THE ANSWER MYSELF FOUND OUT THAT URL WASNT POSTING THE VALUE AND ONCE I PUT IN MANUALLY IT UPDATED SO ITS THE OTHER PAGE THAT NEEDS EDIT BUT THANKS EVERYONE!!!

Comment: Are there any error messages?  What is the output?

Comment: No error just not updating my database total but on the php page it shows that my math1 is being updated whichi is an equation then i have a sql update to grab the math 1 to update total

Comment: You're not checking the value of the query for errors, e.g. `mysql_query($sql3,$con) or die(mysql_error());`.

Comment: found the answer its the other page want posting value through url. thanks anyways

Comment: Also, you should run all your variables through `mysql_real_escape_string()` before using them in a query, as your code is very insecure right now to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). For example, if someone visited... `?id=1;DROP+TABLE+users_colleges;` your code would execute that.

Comment: yea i had die(mysql_error());in there but removed for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap `$math2` in line 30 in quotes, like this:

```
$sql3 = "UPDATE users_colleges SET percentage = '$math2' WHERE college_id = $Vcollege_id";
```

Integers don't need to be contained in quotes, but strings do -- and you added a '%' to `$math2` in line 29, so it's no longer an integer.

Though, not sure if you need to store all the values with the '%' in the database... but if that's what you're doing, it needs to be in quotes.

Comment: hmm i think uve got it let me try this.

Comment: Nope error on that it must have something to do with other page then

Comment: found the answer its the other page want posting value through url. thanks anyways

Comment: ah, okay -- glad to hear you fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the $con from the mysql_query() function calls. I've never had to reiterate a connection call, and it doesn't look like the documentation tells you place a second value in the function call.

Comment: It's not necessary, but I don't think it's a problem. You can pass through the connection, in case you have more than one database connection open. Wouldn't cause problems, just unnecessary with a single connection.

Comment: Well it worked before but now not sure why also it does update votes and thats basiclly the same thing in a way

Comment: found the answer its the other page want posting value through url. thanks anyways